# screen size,element hide & show

Tags: jquery, экран

Подскажите как можно сделать что бы когда РАЗМЕР ЭКРАНА становился ниже указанного то один элемент сворачивался а второй показывался(для маленьких мониторов) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) и создайте стили для нужных размеров экрана.

Пример:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) { ... }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Определите сначала стили для большого экрана, а затем для меньшего размера можете спрятать одни блоки и показать другие.

UPD. [фикс для старых ИЕ](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) может понадобиться

P.S. Это CSS решение. В вопросе указан javascript возможно я не совсем корректно понял задачу. Но если она заключается в разном layout для страниц на больших экранах и на маленьких - то можно обойтись без javascript.

Comment: Ок,спасибо,имеется в виду вещь такая же как на facebooke когда при уменьшении страницы(сжимание браузера) уберется правый чат блок, он сворачивается.

Comment: Media Queries штука интересная - работает динамически. Можете сделать тестовую страничку с 2 блоками разного цвета и помучить браузер. Меняя ширину окна у вас будет динамически срабатывать то одни правила стилей, то другие. [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/wXGvp/1/)

Comment: Спасибо,а можно как нибудь сделать что бы он именно сворачивался,его свернутый вариант этого блока показывался,это тоже возможно с помощью этой функции ?

Comment: Напишите стили развернутого блока в стилях для больших разрешений и стили "свернутого" блока в секции стилей для маленького экрана. [Как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/wXGvp/3/)

Comment: Спасибо,А вопрос,если блок другой должен показаться когда этот скроется ?

Comment: Принцип не меняется. В одной секции пишем стили для нормального состояния сайта, в другой пишем стили для "маленького" окна. Добавьте туда все нужные стили (скройте ненужные и покажите нужные блоки, поменяйте им положение/цвет и рюшечки, добавьте картинок или что еще может понадобиться). Обычная работа с CSS.

Comment: Спасибо,а что используется на facebook вы случ не знаете ?(При маленьком размере окна когда сворачивается правый фиксированный блок чата(превращается в кнопку) ?